# Review audit based on question closed over irreproducibility

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

So, I just got [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7252772) in the First Posts queue, which turned out to be an audit. At first glance, this question seems good. It provides two different inputs and associated outputs, and asks about a perceived inconsistency between them. Sure the last sentence could have slightly better grammar, but since I have less than 2000 rep it didn't seem worth suggesting an edit.

Of course, if you were to actually attempt to answer this question, you would realize that the problem is not reproducible. Which resulted in it being heavily down-voted and closed as off-topic (since "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error" is lumped in with off-topic). Hence it was an audit to which I was supposed to respond with a down-vote or flag.

Am I correct in thinking that this is beyond the scope of what you're supposed to do for review queues? I've always conceived of reviewing as a process of checking posts for clarity, presence of a clear question, presence of sufficient information to answer that question, etc. Thinking about whether or not the question could be the result of a subtle typo seems like a step beyond this. Should I also be checking for potential explanations for problems while I review? Or is this just yet another questionable audit?

Comment: If you don't know the subject matter well enough to be *sure* of what to do, there is always the "Skip" button. That never fails an audit.

Comment: But that's part of my point - I *do* know the subject matter well enough to be sure what to do. It was basically a Python syntax question, and Python is my primary language. But I would have needed to attempt to replicate it in order to catch the error. That would have been the first thing I'd do if I were trying to answer the question, but I tend to think that there is not an expectation that reviewers attempt to replicate problems.